# How does OpenAlias compare with NameID?

Tags: openalias, zookos-triangle

How does [OpenAlias](https://openalias.org/) compare with alternatives such as [NameID](https://nameid.org/)

Which alternative does better at attempting to complete Zooko's Triangle?

Can either OpenAlias or NameID assign aliases based on subdomains?

Which system is more resistant against:

1. Trademark claims?
2. Hacking?
3. Attempts to breach the desire of the owner to keep their identity private?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since OpenAlias supports Namecoin-based identities it has the exact same properties as NameID. The primary advantage to OpenAlias is that it avoids the land-rush issue, where someone grabs the alias `WaffleTown` and then tries to steal payments destined for WaffleTown. Instead, WaffleTown could provide something like `payments.waffletown.com`, without needing to care about the blockchain-based / decentralised scheme.